# AngularJS input[number] doesn't convert "5008" into number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a number input bound to a property that is a string that contains a number.

When displayed the number fails to validate because it is expecting a number and the model then gets set to undefined and the number is never shown.

Aside from manually going in the model and converting it using `parseInt` or something is there anything I can do?

```
<input type="number" ng-model="val.Value" required />
```

The value is actually `5008` before it gets rendered:

```
val.Value = "5008";
```

And once the page gets rendered it gets set to `undefined` by Angular

Comment: did u try to create a directive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Model by default treats the values as strings instead of integers. Binding  it to a number type will not work. you need to handle that logic in the js side and remove the input type=number in the html.

Comment: I want number validation though

Comment: You can add a directive to accept only integers.Else can add a ng-pattern that throws the validation.

Answer (score 1):

you can do a custom directive that put the parseInt before insert in the input

or add a watch on this var and do the parseInt

```
$scope.$watch('val',
        function(newval, oldval) {
            console.log(newval, oldval);
            if (angular.isUndefined($scope.val.Value)) return;
            if (typeof($scope.val.Value) === 'string') $scope.val.Value = parseInt($scope.val.Value);
        }, true
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using "" for value and your input is a type="Number"
I made a jsfiddle for you

http://jsfiddle.net/mv97dhfu/2/

```
$scope.value = 5008;
```

Hope it helps